# Wordpress custom login add text to footer

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am customizing the Wordpress login page and I want to add a text to the bottom of the page. I've already found tutorials that teach you how to add a text above login form but I want to add text to the "footer". How do I do that?
[I want to add the text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhtwy.png)

Thank you in advance for you answer.
Lenka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm refering to the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

You can use an **action hook** for the action `login_footer` to customize the login footer.

```
add_action( 'login_footer', 'your_custom_footer' );

function your_custom_footer() {
    // Add your content here
    echo "<p>I'm a little side note.</p>"
}
```

Comment: would also be worth noting that you could just `echo` the html that you would like in there if you don't want to split the php tags